# Mixing Reverse Polarity Protection PMOS with a Piezo Element

Tags: battery-operated, pmos, piezo, reverse-polarity

I have a circuit that powers some leds when vibrations are detected. I am trying to integrate a PMOS for reverse polarity battery protection.

When the PMOS is present the circuit simulation fails as soon as the piezo (simulated using V1+R1) sine wave starts i.e. TDelay secs. Without the PMOS the circuit works as expected but I don't have any reverse polarity protection.

Is the piezo closing the PMOS?

[image: Area with PMOS and Piezo]

The full circuit
[image: Full Circuit]

Comment: M2 P/N is Pch but schematics shows Nch  Why?

Comment: If M2 really is a PMOS then you need to connect its source to the V2 supply.

Comment: yes it is a PMOS, i followed the example from [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82692/reverse-polarity-protection-pmos-vs-schottkey-diode) for how to connect it for this purpose

Comment: Ah, OK I see what you are doing.