# Mosfet Protection Diode Part Number 3S4L VH10

Tags: mosfet, diodes, surface-mount, reverse-polarity

Mosfet Protection Diode Part Number 3S4L VH10  I can not find it or anything like it. It has 2 leads like a diode, but uses a Mosfet. Very low voltage drop. I am using it for reverse voltage protection as it hooks up to a battery and sometime it can get reversed by accident. It was a fairly new device but does not show up in any search. I would use a substitude if I could find one.

Comment: You can do with that just a PMOS: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82692/reverse-polarity-protection-pmos-vs-schottkey-diode A few more parts if you need to prevent the load from pushing current back towards the supply (for example, if the power supply shows down but the load size still has charge stored in the capacitors or a motor that starts to generate): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223935/understanding-an-ideal-diode-made-from-a-p-channel-mosfet-and-pnp-transistors

Comment: The part has to fit on an already built circuit board. footprint 1210.